# Error Execute Knime in Batch Mode: Unknown option '-workflow'

Tags: knime

I am executing Knime in batch mode (win10 PowerShell) but I am having the following error:

```
ERROR    main BatchExecutor      Unknown option '-workflow'
ERROR    KNIME-ConfigurationArea-Checker ConfigurationAreaChecker        Can't check integrity of configuration area ("C
:\Users\username\Downloads\knime_3.6.0\configuration"): The process cannot access the file because another process has 
locked a portion of the file
```

The command I used is:

```
PS C:\Users\username\Downloads\knime_3.6.0> . .\knime.exe -consoleLog -noexit -nosplash -reset -application org.knime.p
roduct.KNIME_BATCH_APPLICATION -workflowFile="C:\Users\username\Desktop\knime_research\cmd_test2.knwf" -workflow.variab
le=input_csv_path,C:\Users\username\Desktop\knime_research\temp.csv,String
```

Source I went through: 
https://forum.knime.com/t/workflow-cannot-be-saved-anymore/1173/7

Any help will be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Could you clarify which error you have problems with? For the first error I have no idea (though your question on KNIME forum lacks important details like the command used) and the title suggest that is you are most interested in. The other suggest you kept the workflow open in KNIME before starting the execution.

Comment: Thanks for the commends, @Gábor Bakos. Somehow there is something wrong with '.' in PowerShell. It has been fixed [here](https://forum.knime.com/t/unknown-option-workflow-in-batch-mode/12171)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just got an answer from the Knime community. There is something wrong with "." (dot) in `workflow.variable`.

[Here](https://forum.knime.com/t/unknown-option-workflow-in-batch-mode/12171) is the link to the forum.

Thanks for helping out.